# Command for putting backticks around the current word

Tags: vim, markdown

I have to format a lot of files in markdown manually, and I often have to wrap some isolated words in backticks to get them in a code span, ie. : object.method -> `object.method`

I'm using vim and I was wondering how I could write and map to some key a command which would put backticks around the word under cursor, by just pressing F1 for instance ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical answer is to use [surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin by Time Pope that allows to surround easily a selection.(Unless you don't want to install any plugin)

Comment: ``ysiW` `` and ``viWS` `` are both good ways to accomplish your goal using surround

Answer (score 2):

Another (crude) no-plugin solution for the sake of diversity:

```
nnoremap <key> ciw`<C-r>"`<Esc>
xnoremap <key> c`<C-r>"`<Esc>
```

but yeah, just install surround.

Answer (score 2):

[lh-brackets](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhBrackets) has several mappings already defined for markdown:

- backtick will insert a pair of backticks in insert mode, or surround the current word or the current selection (what you were looking for, and that surround also provides with its own "syntax")
- `*` -> `*<cursor>*` ; twice for `**<cursor>**` (`<localleader>*` for surrounding)
- `_` -> `_<cursor>_` ; twice for `__<cursor>__` (`_` for surrounding)
- `~` -> `<del><cursor></del>` (`<localleader>~` for surrounding)
- `<BS>` -> in INSERT mode, deletes an empty pair when the cursor is within it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner you can try:

```
:nmap <F4> :s/\(<c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr>\)/`\1`/<cr>
```

After this command pressing F4 key will do what you want, i.e. replace the word under cursor with the same word surrounded by backticks.

**[UPDATE]**

This may not work for something like object.Method. For this here is a new mapping in visual mode. Select the block of text you want to surround with backtick and press F3

```
:vnoremap <F3> <Esc>`>a`<Esc>`<i`<Esc
```

Comment: xnoremap will be even better.